# Does jQuery-MD5 need jquery to work or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, md5

https://github.com/placemarker/jQuery-MD5
Requirements
None.
If jQuery is not available, the md5 function will be added to the global object
what does this mean?does md5.js need jquery or not?

Comment: It can integrate with jquery, but it doesn't need it.

Comment: "If jQuery is not available, the md5 function will be added to the global object:" Means it is a global method and they show you how to call it....

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't.

jQuery is an optional integration which allows you to compute the MD5 hash via the jQuery `$` variable, like so:

```js
var md5 = $.md5('value');
```

Because it's optional, when not present you will still be able to compute the hash, in the following way:

```js
var md5 = md5('value');
```

You can infer that from the [source code](https://github.com/placemarker/jQuery-MD5/blob/master/jquery.md5.js), which exports the function to the given scope. The scope is defined [here](https://github.com/placemarker/jQuery-MD5/blob/master/jquery.md5.js#L269):

```js
// ...

}(typeof jQuery === 'function' ? jQuery : this));
```

If the jQuery is not defined as a function, the global `this` object will be used. This also means that the code will export the MD5 function to either jQuery or global scope **but not both**, which is likely why this answer has been down-voted.